# users who are not currently part of the windows AD group but still are in the tableau group

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau server V 8.3.

```
How do I get the users who are not currently part of the 
windows AD group but still are in the tableau group
```

Answer (score 2):

1. [Enable external read-only access to the Tableau Server repository](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#adminview_postgres_access.htm)
2. [Get a list of Tableau Server users for the All Users group](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/custom-admin-views-group-membership)
3. Using the method above, get the users for each group on Tableau Server
4. Compare the All Users group against all of the other Tableau Server groups. Any user who is in the All Users group but not any other group should fit your criteria

Comment: thanks! I am not able to get this: Compare the All Users group against all of the other Tableau Server groups.

Comment: Do you have a workbook that shows what you've tried so far? If so, I should be able to test it against my own Tableau Server to see where you may be going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

1. Write a batch script using tab admin's get command to import all the users in tableau local to an xml file.
2. Using the xml file you can create a report.